# uwsgi.ini failed: No such file or directory when running Docker container

Tags: python, docker, uwsgi

I have the following Dockerfile for my Dash app:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.8 AS build

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt /srv/build/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --requirement /srv/build/requirements.txt
COPY . /srv/app

WORKDIR /srv
CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "uwsgi.ini"]
```

Which is being built as follows:

```
docker build -t dashboard .
```

And ran as follows:

```
docker run dashboard
```

The issue is that when I run it, I am encountering the following error:

```
realpath() of uwsgi.ini failed: No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3662]
```

I have been attempting to unpack this more but still struggling. I tried switching around the directory structure of my project and adding uwsgi to the requirements.txt file which I saw recommended in other places. Unfortunately, that didn't fix the issue.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Try basing your image in one image with uwsgi, like https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx/

Comment: Thank you - I am trying that now.